# sorting the column by clicking on the column's header

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I am trying to implement one sorting functionality in my code in php. The functionality will be like, when we click on the header of a column then that particular column's record will be sorted by ascending order and again click on the same column means the column's record will be sorted by descending order.
 Please help me how to proceed with some example.

Comment: The fact that you use php backend is irrelevant if you do the sorting clientside (which you should).

Answer (score 2):

JQuery has many plugins that do this sort of thing. I have used [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) with great results in my own projects.

Answer (score 0):

I too recommend jQuery Tablesorter, it's an excellent little plugin.

You really want to avoid doing the sorting backend, as this will put strain on your server, but if you wanted to it would be as simple as appending an ORDER BY instruction to your query depending on what column the user clicked. Again, I do not recomment this method, I think you should do it in the frontend with a plugin such as Tablesorter.